# Naive question on the SN1 mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was teaching the $S_N1$ mechanism to a friend. He asked a question a subtle question I can't shake off. Take a tertiary alkyl halide and aqueous sodium hydroxide. The first step is the formation of the carbocation. My friend asked how did the alkyl halide just do that all of a sudden. What about the presence of the $\ce{NaOH}$ made this compound do this if it doesn't even interact with it ( in the first step)? I first thought maybe it was just that the first step is something that is a feasible process, and that the alkyl halide would do (to an appreciable extent) that even without the $\ce{NaOH}$, but I am not sure.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: The solvation of the halide part led to energy being released which compensated for the bond being broken(which apparently seems "spontaneous")

Comment: So this would have happened even without the NaOH present?

Comment: Heard of the term solvolysis if not look it up